# How to correctly deal with references in custom controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, custom-controls

I built a class library exporting two custom controls using c#. This class library depends on some references, which are duly copied into the bin\Debug directory on build (of a solution using the custom controls) as long as I add only the controls DLL as reference. So far, so good.

If I now add the controls from that output directory into the toolbox and place one on an empty form in the designer, visual studio crashes. If I debug from the custom control solution like so http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ytx0z24(VS.80).aspx, I can see the IO exception that one of the referenced DLLs cannot be found.

So, is there a reasonably elegant way of placing the dependencies for the *designer* to find them? I tried fiddling with the reference paths in the project settings, but to no avail. I would prefer to avoid setting system-wide paths and installing/registering the control every time I change a bit of code.

Comment: can you tell me please which dll cannot be found ? the dll which added explicitly by you ?

Comment: One of the DLLs that are referenced by my custom control cannot be found. these DLLs do not explicitly appear in the references list, but are copied into the bin directory on build because visual studio detects those dependencies. Even adding all of them to the project references does not help the designer find them.

Comment: after you added to the references did you call it on the page explicitly ?

Comment: What do you mean? Which page? BTW, if I add the control programmatically, it works fine when running my application.

Comment: if i don't misunderstand when  you add your custom control / references in another namespace it doesn't work, right ?

it has few reasons..1-) you use both obfuscation at debug and code optimisation option together 2-) you didn't set your dll reference to copyLocale option 3-) you didn't call your dll from references list and/or in the form where you want to use your control, explicitly 4-) one or more parts of your dll or main project are not signed and the other signed.. check these and let me knowledge please.. BTW if you don't write your error or error code noone can help you as a point..

Comment: 1) no 2) I did, which is why the question AND comment #2 state "which are duly copied..." 3) I tried explicit references, that does not help 4) nothing is signed and I can only add "FileNotFoundException was unhandled. Could not load file or assembly (one of my assemblies - see question) or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.". I hoped I had stated that clearly enough...

Comment: so many 3rd party developer signs or set delay sign of their codes..if you didn't sign your code and the dll which you try to use is signed you get this error..even delay signing don't permit to debug the assembly/dll..did you tell this to the developer of this dll ?

and so little percentage..Do you call as reference which you copied to app.path? or you copied and called another copy ? (i.e. where the file you downloaded firstly fo your dll)

and.. if you van add it programatically then go on this way..why you wait to add as reference ?

Comment: If the 'Reference Paths' doesn't work as you say, then you could try manually loading the dlls (System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile) inside the constructor of your custom control (only doing the manual load if this.DesignMode is set).  I tend to avoid the designer for many reasons similar to this so I am not sure if it will work, but it's worth a shot!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just reference the project as a whole rather than manually copying in the dll?  If you have a good reason for this then fine, but it seems as though you are asking a question which doesn't need to be asked! :P

Comment: Nice try, but this question really needs to be asked since including the project in the solution and then referencing it does not help. The dll that is not found is, as stated above, a reference of the referenced project. And no, adding the missing reference explicitly to the project using the custom component does not help. The dll is still not found and the IO exception is thrown.

Comment: OK, so you're saying that adding a reference to the project output rather than the DLLs doesn't work?  That's very strange... Event stranger than not being able to find the DLL!  Is there any chance you   could put a project online which has the same problem?  We may be able to help more if you provide us with a (not) working example!

Comment: I repeat, we are talking about nested references. Referencing a project or a dll works fine, but the stuff referenced by the referenced project is not found.

Comment: @Keiichi - So let me confirm.  ProjectA references ProjectB, ProjectB has a reference to a DLL, but when you invoke a method (or similar) in ProjectB from ProjectA which requires the DLL it fails?  If that's the case (you've already said you have set CopyLocal correctly), then why can't you create a sample project which is set up the same (project A -> Project B -> DLL) and let us see it to help you?  It would take two minutes if we have something to work with!  Also, there is no need for the rudeness just because you had to rephrase something because it wasn't clear, I'm only trying to help!